# I'm trying to call a function within the return function - undefined

Tags: reactjs

I want to call a function in my render method within a map function, the result of which is then stored in a variable. I would like to insert this variable into my DOM. But with the variable I get an undefined. For what reason ?

```
function ladeAlleAnhaengeEinerAufgaben(aufgabe) {
const data = new FormData();
data.append("task_id_in", aufgabe.task_id);

axios.post(url + "AlleAnhaengeEinerAufgabe", data).then(function (resp) {
  if (resp.data.length > 0) {
    return (
      <Badge
        badgeContent={resp.data.length}
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => oeffneAufgabe(aufgabe)}
      >
        <InsertDriveFileIcon />
      </Badge>
    );
  }
  return (
    <Badge
      badgeContent={0}
      color="primary"
      onClick={() => oeffneAufgabe(aufgabe)}
    >
      <InsertDriveFileIcon />
    </Badge>
  );
  });
 }
```

And in my render Method:

```
   {alleAufgaben.map((aufgabe) => {
      //badged is undefinded
      let badged = ladeAlleAnhaengeEinerAufgaben(aufgabe);
      return (
           [...]
           <ListItemSecondaryAction>{badged}</ListItemSecondaryAction>
            );
    })}
```

Comment: In React render method/functions are pure, synchronous functions. You can't call asynchronous functions and expect to return anything renderable from them, React just doesn't wait. You will want to store the result of the POST request into local state and render the UI/JSX from data stored in state.

Answer (score 0):

You're making an API call and try to return a value after you get a response. But React won't wait for that. Try sth like this:

```
function ladeAlleAnhaengeEinerAufgaben(aufgabe) {
  ...
  return await axios.post(...)
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In React render method/functions are pure, synchronous functions. You can't call asynchronous functions and expect to return anything renderable from them, React just doesn't wait. You will want to store the result of the POST request into local state and render the UI/JSX from data stored in state.

```
const [badgeData, setBadgeData] = React.useState([]);
```

Return the axios Promise from the POST request so `ladeAlleAnhaengeEinerAufgaben` can be used as the map callback to create a map of Promises to be called in a mounting `useEffect` hook. The resolved value is an array of all the POST responses, in order, to be saved into state.

```
function ladeAlleAnhaengeEinerAufgaben(aufgabe) {
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append("task_id_in", aufgabe.task_id);

  return axios.post(url + "AlleAnhaengeEinerAufgabe", data);
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  Promise.all(alleAufgaben.map(ladeAlleAnhaengeEinerAufgaben))
    .then(resp => setBadgeData(resp));
}, []);
```

Render the saved array of `badge` data.

```
return (
  ...
  badgeData.map(badge => (
    <ListItemSecondaryAction>
      <Badge
        badgeContent={badge.data.length}
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => oeffneAufgabe(aufgabe)}
      >
        <InsertDriveFileIcon />
      </Badge>
    </ListItemSecondaryAction>
  ))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting `undefined` because you returned nothing from your `ladeAlleAnhaengeEinerAufgaben` function.

The path you took to solve the problem is not correct. first, we have to consider the possible mods, lemme define some state/example:

1. loading: your data is loading from API
2. error:   there is a problem with data fetching
3. data:    data fetched successfully!

NOTE: if you used functional components, you could use react-query that was very comfortable + some cool features (but there is a trick to use `useQuery` with a class component, [eg](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/discussions/1558)).

and here is a pseudocode example:

```
function ladeAlleAnhaengeEinerAufgaben() {
  return axios.post(url + 'AlleAnhaengeEinerAufgabe', data);
}

class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      isError: false,
      data: undefined,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ladeAlleAnhaengeEinerAufgaben()
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200)
          this.setState({
            data: res.data,
          });
        else
          this.setState({
            isError: true,
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => this.setState({ isError: true }))
      .finally(() => this.setState({ isLoading: false }));
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) return <h1>Hold on...</h1>;
    if (this.state.isError) return <b>Ooops! we have an error!</b>;
    return (
      <>
        <Badge
          badgeContent={this.state.data.length}
          color="primary"
          onClick={() => oeffneAufgabe(aufgabe)}
        >
          <InsertDriveFileIcon />
        </Badge>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```